# Can I store data that won't affect query performance in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, performance, binary-data

We have an application which requires saving of data that should be in documents, for querying and sorting purposes. The data should be schema less, as some of the fields would be known only via usage. For this, MongoDB is a great solution and it works great for us.

Part of the data in each document, is for displaying purposes. Meaning the data can be objects (let's say json) that the client side uses in order to plot diagrams.

I tried to save this data using gridfs, but the use cases makes it not responsive enough. Also, the documents won't exceed the 16 MB limits even with the diagram data inside them. And in fact, while trying to save this data directly within the documents, we got better results.

This data is used only for client side responses, meaning we should never query it. So my question is, can I insert this data to MongoDB, and set it as a 'not for query' data? Meaning, can I insert this data without affecting Mongo's performance? The data is strict and once a document is inserted, there might be only updating of existing fields, not adding new ones.

I've noticed there is a Binary Data type in Mongo, and I am wondering if I should use this type for objects that are not binary. Can this give me what I'm looking for?
Also, I would love to know what is the advantage in using this type inside my documents. Can it save me disk space?

Comment: It is a somewhat broader issue than you might realize. But in general principle there is nothing wrong with "embedding" such data into each document and only actually using it within the requests that actually ask for it. In such a case, you generally want to take care to ["exclude"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-all-but-the-excluded-fields) such a property from "general query" results, otherwise it will be returned even if other display logic does not reference it.

Comment: You might also consider indexing for a ["covered query"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query). Where the only fields actually used in the query condition are the only ones returned. Combined with ["specific inclusion"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-id-field-only) this is the most efficient way to return such data, where it is possible to only return the fields that were part of the query condition that is.

Comment: So as for the `Binary` type. This is exactly what your "embedded property" would use. And therefore the only difference from `GridFS` would be that the actual data resides "along with it's parent", as opposed to merely a "reference" to an object that actually resides in other collections. The "chunks" of GridFS, merely stores each "chunk" of bytes as the `Binary` type. `GridFS` is also "just software", and at a "driver" level. MongoDB itself has no special handling of `GridFS`. It's just regular collections and documents as far as the server is concerned.

Comment: @NeilLunn  Thank you very much for the clear and informative answer. It was exactly what I was looking for, so consider to post it as an answer. One more question though, can you please elaborate why Binary type is exactly what I should use? I've noticed that this fields are available for query as well, so I'm not sure what is the added valued for using them.

Answer (score 0):

As at MongoDB 3.4, read and write operations are atomic on the level of a single document from the storage/memory point of view. If the MongoDB server needs to fetch a document from memory or disk (even when [projecting a subset of fields to return](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)) the full document generally has to be loaded into memory on a `mongod`. The only exception is if you can [take advantage of covered queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) where all of the fields returned are also included in the index used.

> This data is used only for client side responses, meaning we should never query it.

Data fields which aren't queried directly do not need to be in any indexes. However, there is currently no concept like "not for query" fields in MongoDB. You can query or project any field (with or without an index).

> Meaning, can I insert this data without affecting Mongo's performance?

Data with very different access or growth patterns (such as your infrequently requested client data) is a recommended candidate for storing separately from a parent document with frequently accessed data. This will improve the efficiency of memory usage for  `mongod` by avoiding unnecessary retrieval of data when working with documents in the parent collection.

> I've noticed there is a Binary Data type in Mongo, and I am wondering if I should use this type for objects that are not binary. Can this give me what I'm looking for? Also, I would love to know what is the advantage in using this type inside my documents. Can it save me disk space?

You should use a type that is most appropriate for the data that you are storing. Storing text data as binary will not gain you any obvious efficiencies in server storage. However, storing a complex object as a single value (for example, a JSON document serialized as a string) could save some serialization overhead if that object will only be interpreted via your client-side code. Binary data stored in MongoDB will be an opaque blob as far as indexing or querying, which sounds fine for your purposes.